# Presionar botón con tecla enter

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo el siguiente Modal:

```
  <div class="modal fade" id="ModeloNoRegistrado" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="container" style="text-align:center;">
            <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
              <h4 class="alert-heading">El Modelo no está registrado</h4>
              <span>Comuníquese con su supervisor para dar de alta un modelo.</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a href="../inventario.php" class="btn btn-danger">Cerrar</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

y quisiera que al presionar la tecla 'Enter' de mi teclado se ejecute el 'a href', espero su respuesta y de antemano, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veo que usas `bootstrap`. Corrígeme si estoy errado, por favor.

Puedes usar el método `shown.bs.modal` de `bootstrap`. Así, al abrir el modal, haces `focus` en el botón y al presionar la tecla enter, se redirige al usuario a la pagina que especifiques en el `link`

```js
//Al mostrar el modal
$('#ModeloNoRegistrado').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  //Hago focus en el botón
  $('#myButton').trigger('focus')
  //así al presionar enter, se redirecciona a la pgina que pongas en el link
})
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModeloNoRegistrado">
      Abrir modal
    </button>
    <div class="modal fade" id="ModeloNoRegistrado" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="container" style="text-align:center;">
              <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                <h4 class="alert-heading">El Modelo no está registrado</h4>
                <span>Comuníquese con su supervisor para dar de alta un modelo.</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <a href="https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/337680/presionar-bot%c3%b3n-con-tecla-enter" class="btn btn-danger" id="myButton">Cerrar</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Algo de documentación al respecto: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/modal/

Comment: Gracias!! me sirvió mucho!!

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo de esta manera

```
$(function() {
  if($("#ModeloNoRegistrado").modal('show'))
    if(e.which == 13){
      mifuncion();
    }
})

function mifuncion(){
window.locationf="../inventario.php";
}
```